# return to command line when program output is done

Tags: java, multithreading, command-line, command-prompt

Wrote a multi-thread program to print out odd and even numbers in sequence untill the sequence reached 30.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class NumPrintTX
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int max = 31;
    final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Executor dd = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    final Object lock = new Object();

    dd.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (i.get() < max)
            {
                if (i.get() % 2 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + i.getAndAdd(1));

                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    dd.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (i.get() < max)
            {
                if (i.get() % 2 != 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + i.getAndAdd(1));

                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    do
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    while (i.get() != max);
}
}
```

when the program runs, it comes out just fine, but it won't go to the next line so i could enter another command for whatever i want to do next.  Any ideas why this is and what i can do to fix it?

modified code:
    import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

```
public class NumPrintTX
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int max = 31;
    final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Executor dd = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    final Object lock = new Object();

    dd.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (i.get() < max)
            {
                if (i.get() % 2 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + i.getAndAdd(1));

                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    dd.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (i.get() < max)
            {
                if (i.get() % 2 != 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + i.getAndAdd(1));

                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(lock)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    do
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    while (i.get() != max);
}
public void close()
{
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not stopping your thread pool, so it's not letting your main program end.

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Worker implements Runnable {
    private AtomicInteger i;
    private Object lock;
    private int max;
    private int mod;

    Worker(AtomicInteger i_, Object lock_, int max_, int mod_){ 
        this.i   = i_;
        this.lock = lock_;
        this.max  = max_;
        this.mod  = mod_; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (i.get() < max)
        {
            if(i.get() % 2 == mod)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + i.getAndAdd(1));

                synchronized(lock){ lock.notify(); }
            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(lock)
                {
                    try { lock.wait(); }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class NumPrintTX
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int max = 31;
        final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ExecutorService dd = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        final Object lock = new Object();

        dd.execute(new Worker(i, lock, max, 0));
        dd.execute(new Worker(i, lock, max, 1));

        dd.shutdown();
    }    
}
```

Without the `dd.shutdown()`, your program will hang despite getting to the end.

The main do-while loop and `System.exit(0)` will work but seems a bit "brute-force".

Also, this code streamlines your thread code and makes it much more readable without changing the underlying logic.

Comment: could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Tried that. when i went to compile it, it gave me a `error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: It compiles fine for me -- did you copy the whole thing including imports?  Can you give me a more specific error message?

Comment: Also note that `dd` is an `ExecutorService`, not simply an `Executor` -- fixing this allows you to access to the `shutdown()` method.

Comment: the imports are there, it looks like they didn't get formatted in w/ the rest of the coding. the original and modified coding have the same imports, so if you need those they would be pretty much at the very top.

Comment: Oh, I missed them, sorry!  Adding them now

Comment: gotcha. added the `ExecutorService` import and im still getting the same error message when i try to compile it.

Comment: Did you change the line from `Executor dd ...` to `ExecutorService dd ...`?

Comment: on the imports or in the shutdown method?

Comment: Neither, 3rd line of main function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the program with a call to `System.exit(0);` where `0` is the exit status code for a "normal" exit. The call should be made after your loop that prints out the numbers has completed.

[Java Docs for System.exit(int status)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

Answer (score -1):

You need to expressly close your program. So, something like this:

```
public void close() {
    // Put any closing code here, like joining Threads or whatever
    System.exit(0); // 0 means it is a normal exit, i.e. there are no errors
}
```

Comment: You have to actually call the method at the point where you want your program to end, you can't just put it in there and expect it to happen. >_<